# Exporting fabric.js canvas to printable file

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, fabricjs

I'm working on an online app for designing custom scarves. After initial research I have found the I can use Fabric.js for this purpose. However I am newbie when it comes to 2D design and canvas. I want to provide the user with a canvas where they can upload images/pattern and design there scarf.

The scarf size is 90*90 cm. And I had a requirement to provide the scarf design in actual size to the printing company in Eps/AI format or a high resolution image file . This is where I get kinda lost. What size would the canvas be.. and how can I make sure if the images uploaded are of high resolution.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

90 cm is about 34inches.
If you consider for hi res, let's say 150 DPI you will get something like 5000x5000 canvas.

Now 5000 x 5000 is a 25 Mega pixel picture, hard to handle for a browser.
You can try to create a 5000 x 5000 fabric canvas you will experience terrible performances.

What you can do is export in SVG with canvas.toSVG() and then raster the SVG to a PNG or JPEG with a library of your choice that can handle big files.

Comment: is the right strategy to create a small canvas  and then scale it to a 5000x5000 image on serverside?

Comment: depends on the scaler. fabricjs on nodejs uses a lot of memory anyway. but if node-canvas is more flexible than standard html5 canvas it could be. i'm currently searching a good svg rasterizer on server to solve this.

Comment: I'm trying to use imagemagick on the server?  Also what if you have a canvas of 150x150pixels but you upload an image that is 1000x1000, it would be huge on the canvas. are there any strategies to auto scale this down?

Comment: Thanks @AndreaBogazzi, For now the way i am handling this is 1) use canvas.toDataURL(1,'png') and save it as png on server 2) save the canvas using JSON.stringify(canvas) for editing purpose. 

To get the high resolution image (300 dpi) and scaling the image (for printing) I am using GIMP.